# Make slaves wait for each other in MPI

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, synchronization, mpi

I have a master-slave model in my MPI program. I want to make slaves wait for each other before going to the next iteration.

```
if (rank == 0) {
    // master process
} else {
    // slave process
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // do stuff
        // wait for all slaves to end iteration i
    }
}
```

Basically, I don't want any processor to go into next iteration without all other slaves complete their current iteration. How can I do this? With `MPI_Barrier`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a communicator comprising with all slave processes and use it on a `MPI_Barrier()`.
Fro creating this communicator, the simplest / safest is to use `MPI_Comm_split()` this way:

```
MPI_Comm slaves;
MPI_Comm_split( MPI_COMM_WORLD, ( rank == 0 ), rank, &slaves );
```

This will actually globally create 2 communicators: one comprising only the master process and one comprising all processes but the master.

For actual use, you can do it this way:

```
if (rank == 0) {
    // master process
} else {
    // slave process
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        // do stuff
        // wait for all slaves to end iteration i
        MPI_Barrier( slaves );
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a harm. Can you also take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706087/check-if-adjacent-slave-process-is-ended-in-mpi)?

Comment: Also, what if I change for loop to while and one slave iterate in while 3 times, the other 5 times, the other 12 times. It would go to deadlock, yeah? How can I prevent it?

Comment: Yes it would deadlock. Question becomes, why do you want to synchronise in the first place?

Comment: Because I need updated information from other processors in each step. I need it in my algorithm.

Comment: You can simply make all of you slaves to iterate as many times and simply check if the current iteration is smaller than their individual max. And right after the closing of the `if` statement, you add the `MPI_Barrier()`. It is sort of wasteful for the resources, but only if the processes could do something else. And at least, it will work and you'll be able to assess whether you need to further optimise from there.